# Zip file download/progress on browser C#, Angular

Tags: c#, angular

I have two files(mp4 and json) to be downloaded via Angular -> C#.

With the below code I see transfer is done on network tab on console but I want to achieve/see the download progress on browser side.

Download file shows up on browser after complete download is done on network

C# Code

```
   [HttpPost]
   public async Task DownloadZip(Model model)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.Headers.Add($"Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + model.Item2 + ".zip\"");
            using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(Response.BodyWriter.AsStream(), ZipArchiveMode.Create))
            {
                await CreateJsoninZip("zipFileName.json", archive);
                await CreateVideoinZip("zipFileName.mp4", mp4Path, archive);
            }
        }



   private static async Task CreateJsoninZip(string fileName, ZipArchive archive)
        {
            var jsonEntry = archive.CreateEntry($"fileName.json");
            using (var entryStream = jsonEntry.Open())
            using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@$"C:\Temp\downloadJson\temp.json"))
            {
                await fileStream.CopyToAsync(entryStream);
            }
        }



  private static async Task CreateVideoinZip(string fileName, string filePath, ZipArchive archive)
    {
        var videoEntry = archive.CreateEntry(fileName);
        using (var entryStream = videoEntry.Open())
        using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@$"C:\Temp\downloadJson\temp.mp4"))
        {
            await fileStream.CopyToAsync(entryStream);
        }
    }
```

Angular Code

```
downloadZip(url: string, postData: any) {
    return this.http.post(url, postData, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      }),
      responseType: 'blob'
    });
  }

click()
{
   downloadZip(apiUrl, model)
      .subscribe(result => {
        const filename = "xyz.zip";
        let blob = new Blob([result], { type: "application/zip" });
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = filename;
        link.click();
      }
      );
}
```

PS: When I call api directly from browser, the download starts right away to browser downloads. Looking for same via angular.

Answer (score 0):

the return type of the downloadZip() function is `Observable<HttpEvent<Blob>>`
which emits an event on every loaded chunk of the file. so, you could do:

```
downloadZip(apiUrl, model)
  .subscribe(result => {
    switch (result.type) {
      case HttpEventType.DownloadProgress:
        if (event && event.total) {
          const progress = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
          console.log('downloaded: ' + progress + ' %')
        }
      break;
      case HttpEventType.Response:
        const filename = "xyz.zip";
        let blob = new Blob([result], { type: "application/zip" });
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = filename;
        link.click();
      break;
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: But with this I will be able to check the transfer but not show download on browser. with this user has to stay on the page for the download to complete

Comment: you can rely on the progress value to show a progress bar or an indicator in your app, the download operation is asynchronous so it doesn't block the user interaction, you just need to build your app in a way that the download happens in the background and is not coupled to a component lifecycle.

Comment: But user can leave the website, then the user cannot see any updates about the download.
One more thing with above code is when I open api on browser, it starts downloading right away.
Looking for a way in angular to start downloading immediately on to the browser downloads